# How to add a link on woocommerce product page as per the product category?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was able to find a code to add a link on woocommerce product page but I want to add a link as per the product category. Following is the code that I added to display the link on the product page. Can someone please help me get the code to add the link to the product page as per the product category?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 
'content_before_addtocart_button' );

function content_before_addtocart_button() {
echo '<div class="content-section">add custom size <a 
 href="http://google.com">here</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: You want to show a link to the product category to be displayed?  What is a product has multiple categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in your functions.php file it will output a link if the category slug matches 'jackets' in this instance.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'content_before_addtocart_button' );

function content_before_addtocart_button() {
    global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if( $term->slug === 'jackets')
            echo '<div class="content-section">add custom size <a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_cat' ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your fast reply, let me elaborate my issue a bit more. Actually, the code that I have shared in my post is fine and correct. All i want to do is that i want to insert a link to the product page in a specific category. For example. If i have 3 Product categories, Jackets, shoes, shirts. How would I be able to insert a link to the products that belong to the category of jackets?

Comment: @danish I've updated my answer to output a link if the category slug of jackets is found on a product.

Comment: @danish you're welcome, if you could accept my answer that would be fantastic :)